# What is the difference between Jinja's defined vs if variable_name?

Tags: jinja2

What is the difference between these two items? When do you use one vs the other?

```
{% if x is defined %} 
   words
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% if x %}
   words
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one enforces you to provide x as a variable. If you won't set x at all, then it'll be an error. The first item will be skipped if x wasn't provided